# Most generic f in R4 who send straight lines in straight lines

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, reference-request

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ is invertible and sends every straight lines onto straight lines; more precisely (this is a stronger request) every curve $t->At+B$ has to be sent in another $t->A't+B'$, ossia also the "constance" of the velocity has to be preserved. Is $f$ always of the form $f(x) = Ax + b$ for a vector $b$ and a matrix $A$?

If yes, where I can find some references?

MOTIVATION: Correct foundation of special relativity, avoiding every extra- not necessary-hypotesis, and the imprecisions found in a lot of Physics' textbooks.

Comment: Are we requiring $f:\mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R^4$ to map every straight line to a straight line?  Is it possible that a straight line is mapped to a point?

Comment: No...literally, i d wish that every uniform motion has to be mapped onto an uniform motion...so if I have a linear trajectory, when I do the trasformation I have to find another linear trajectory. So every straight lines has to be mapped onto a straight lines. A lot of textbook says that is implies that trasformation must to be affine, but i'm diffident...and I don't want to suppose that f has to be differentiable,  or other not minimal hypotesis.... i require only invertibility

Comment: Please include that extra information in the question post.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collineation

Comment: If i make my request stronger: i don't want to preserve only the "shape", but every curve of the type t->At+B, A,B vectors, has to be sent to another curve of the type t->A't+B'...i want to preserve also the constance of the velocities.
Is this enough to have the affinity? Can i Have some reference if yes?

Comment: In fact the "stronger" condition (preserving the magnitude of velocity) makes the proof easier, because the map is now distance preserving.  In any Euclidean space the distance preserving maps (isometries) are compositions of orthogonal transformations and translations, i.e. the affine transformations corresponding to orthogonal transformations plus an offset vector.

Comment: Interesting...the fact that f must be an isometry is not trivial. I'm stating that if for all s(k): k -≥ Ak+B there exists A', B' s.t. f(s(k))=A'k+B', then we can state that f is an isometry: f(x)Tf(y) = xTy

Comment: I see, you are not asking that the magnitude of velocity (speed) is preserved (that would be an isometry), but rather that linear paths of constant velocity are mapped to linear paths of (a possibly different) constant velocity.  Such a mapping does not have to be an isometry, e.g. if we stretch the domain $\mathbb R$ by different scalings in different directions (anisotropically but in an invertible linear transformation), then velocities will be altered.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$tl; dr: Yes. A sketch of a proof follows.

---

Suppose $f$ is a bijection of Cartesian four-space and maps lines to lines, preserving constant-velocity paths (but not necessarily an isometry).

**Lemma 1**: The image of every plane is a plane.

*Proof*: Assume contrapositively that there exists a plane $P$ and points $q_{1}$ and $q_{2}$ of $f(P)$ such that the segment $\overline{q_{1}q_{2}}$ is not contained in $f(P)$. Because $f$ is a bijection of $\Reals^{4}$, it is a bijection from $P$ to $f(P)$. Consequently, there exist unique points $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ of $P$ with $q_{i} = f(p_{i})$. The segment $\overline{p_{1}p_{2}} \subset P$ does not map to $\overline{q_{1}q_{2}}$, so $f$ does not map lines to lines.

**Lemma 2**: $f$ maps parallel lines to parallel lines.

*Proof*: Two distinct parallel lines lie in a plane $P$. By Lemma 1, the image lines also lie in a plane, and are disjoint, hence parallel.

**Lemma 3**: The mapping $f_{0}(x) = f(x) - f(0)$ is linear.

*Proof*: The mapping $f_{0}$ preserves constant-speed lines (as a composition of transformations with this property), and by construction $f_{0}(0) = 0$. Particularly, if $y$ is an arbitrary vector, then
$$
f_{0}(ty) = tf_{0}(y)\quad\text{for all real $t$.}
$$
Now let $x$ and $y$ be arbitrary vectors. If $t$ is real, the vector $x + ty$ parametrizes a constant-speed line parallel to the line $ty$. By Lemma 2, $f_{0}(x + ty)$ parametrizes a constant-speed line, passing through $f_{0}(x)$ when $t = 0$ and parallel to the line $f_{0}(ty) = tf_{0}(y)$. That is,
$$
f_{0}(x + ty) - f_{0}(x) = tf_{0}(y),
$$
or $f_{0}(x + ty) = f_{0}(x) + tf_{0}(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$ in $\Reals^{4}$ and all real $t$.

**Lemma 4**: If $f(0) = 0$ and for each standard basis vector $e_{i}$ we have $f(e_{i}) = e_{i}$, then $f$ is the identity.

*Proof*: By Lemma 3, $f$ is linear. Since $f$ fixes the standard basis, $f$ is the identity.

**Lemma 5**: There exist an invertible matrix $A$ and a vector $b$ such that $f(x) = Ax + b$ for all $x$.

*Proof*: Let $b = f(0)$, $f_{0}(x) = f(x) - b$ as in Lemma 3, and let $A$ be the matrix with $i$th column $f_{0}(e_{i}) = f(e_{i}) - f(0)$. Because $f_{0}$ is linear and bijective, $A$ is invertible.

But the mapping $g(x) = A^{-1}f_{0}(x) = A^{-1}(f(x) - b)$ preserves constant-speed lines (again, as a composition of transformations with this property), and by construction $g(0) = 0$ and $g(e_{i}) = e_{i}$ for each $i$. Lemma 4 implies $g$ is the identity, i.e., that $f(x) = Ax + b$.

Comment: In lemma 3, where did you find the property $f_0(ty) = t f_0(y)$? From hypotesis we can say $f(ty) =t'f(y) + B$. Not necessarily $t =t'$, and furthermore we could have an offset B which is not trivial... Another observation...there are collineations, that are maps that preserves lines to lines but they're not linear...why this proof does not apply to them?

Comment: We know $f_0(ty) = t'f_0(y)$ for $t' = kt + t_0$ some affine function of $t$ because $f_0(ty)$ is a line through the origin. Setting $t = 0$ tells us $t_0=0$, and setting $t = 1$ gives $k = 1$. <> Lemma 2 guarantees that $f$ maps parallelograms to parallelograms, which projective collineations do not generally do. (In case it helps, the fact that $f_0$ preserves the origin expresses geometrically the condition $f_0(x+y)=f_0(x)+f_0(y)$ for all $x$ and $y$.) <> I can edit these points into the answer, but will wait to be sure you're happy with these extra details to avoid multiple edits.

Comment: Regarding the collineations, I'm reflecting about the fact that in the hypotesis we're requiring f bijection, and collineations have got a whole line out of their domain!<>
Why this? $t' = kt+t_0$. If we have $f_0(ty)=t' f_0(y) we can't argue a form for t'(t)...the parametrization could be generic...

Comment: There is the domain issue, as well. <> We're assuming constant-speed lines map to constant-speed lines, which guarantees $t'$ is an affine function of $t$.