# A book or script with a proof for the fundamental theorem of affine geometry with a linear algebra background.

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation, affine-geometry

I am looking for a source for the proof of the fundamental theorem of affine geometry in a linear algebra setting. The theorem I mean is: "If $f \colon \mathbb A^n \to \mathbb A^n$ is a bijection of an affine space onto itself that maps lines to lines, then $f$ is an affine transformation".
I don't mind if it's a book or lecture notes. I have been having a bit of trouble finding a source that proves this theorem. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198298/most-generic-f-in-r4-who-send-straight-lines-in-straight-lines) is not quite a duplicate (OP assumed the image of every _constant-speed_ line is a constant-speed line), but may be of interest.